# Does this theorem/collection of theorems have a name? Or is it just seen as obvious?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, definition, universal-algebra, morphism

After some thought I realized that given any sets $X$ and $Y$ with equal cardinality and an arbitrary bijection $f:X\to Y$ we get that the set of all bijections from $X$ to $Y$ is given by:

$$\{f\circ \sigma:\sigma\in \text{Sym}(X)\}=\{\sigma\circ f:\sigma\in \text{Sym}(Y)\}$$

Then when I recently learned about the definition of isomorphism/automorphism between sets equipped with binary operations i.e. $(X,*)\cong (Y,\cdot)\iff f(x*y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$ for some bijection $f:X\to Y$, I found that the set of all isomorphisms from $(X,*)$ to $(Y,\cdot)$ is given by:

$$\{f\circ \sigma:\sigma\in \text{Aut}(X)\}=\{\sigma\circ f:\sigma\in \text{Aut}(Y)\}$$

Where $\text{Aut}(X)$ and $\text{Aut}(Y)$ are the set of all automorphisms on $(X,*)$ and $(Y,\cdot)$ respectively. Well it turns out this holds for even more general algebraic structures with operations of arbitrary arity using this definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism#Definition i.e. if $(X,\mu_X)\cong (Y,\mu_Y)\iff f(\mu_X(x_1,\ldots x_n))=\mu_Y(f(x_1),\ldots f(x_n))$ for a bijection $f:X\to Y$ then we again get:

$$\{f\circ \sigma:\sigma\in \text{Aut}(X)\}=\{\sigma\circ f:\sigma\in \text{Aut}(Y)\}$$

Where $\text{Aut}(X)$ and $\text{Aut}(Y)$ are the set of all automorphisms on $(X,\mu_X)$ and $(Y,\mu_Y)$ i.e. bijections $g:X\to X$ or $h:Y\to Y$ with the property:

$$g(\mu_X(x_1,\ldots x_n))=\mu_X(g(x_1),\ldots g(x_n))$$
$$h(\mu_Y(y_1,\ldots y_n))=\mu_Y(h(y_1),\ldots h(y_n))$$

How far can this be generalized? Even for "isomorphisms" between binary relations, that is bijective maps which preserve relations I found an analog of this theorem holds. That is the set of all isomorphisms between two relations can be expressed as any isomorphism between them composed with every automorphism on $X$ or $Y$ between them either left or right composed with said function.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism#Relation-preserving_isomorphism

I mean I don't really have a clear definition of "isomorphism" for general mathematical objects, just for algebraic structures, relations, and a few others. However it always seems this sort of theorem or an anlog of it holds. Does this fact/theorem have a name? Or is it just seen as obvious?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an artifact of [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory). The actual theorem it describes is rather trivial - the hard part is choosing the right definitions.

In particular, a *category* can be defined by a collection of objects with maps between them called *morphisms*. For instance, there is a category of sets where the objects are sets, and a morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ is simply a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$. There is a category of groups, whose objects are groups $(X,\cdot)$ and a map $(X,\cdot)\rightarrow (Y,*)$ is a homomorphism between these groups. You can similarly define a category of operations of a given arity (or, in universal algebra, of a given signature - which encompasses objects like rings).

More or less, a category is supposed to have a notion of composition - meaning that if I take a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and a map $g:Y\rightarrow Z$, then there is a map $g\circ f:X\rightarrow Z$. Functions and homomorphisms are closed under composition, so our examples are good. One requires that composition be associative and that, for every object $X$, there is an identity map $\operatorname{id}_X:X\rightarrow X$ which is an identity for composition.

Then, one defines an isomorphism as follows:

> An isomorphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism such that there exists an inverse $g:Y\rightarrow X$. That is, a map such that $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_Y$ and $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_X$. This $g$ is known as $f^{-1}$.

So, in the category of sets, the isomorphisms are the bijections. In the category of groups, the isomorphisms are exactly what is usually called an isomorphism - and your extended notion of isomorphism also corresponds to a categorical one in the right category.

We also have the following definition:

> An automorphism of an object $X$ is an isomorphism $f:X\rightarrow X$.

Then, your claim is essentially the following:

> If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:X\rightarrow Y$ are an isomorphisms, then there is a $\sigma\in \operatorname{Aut}(X)$ such that $g=f\circ \sigma$ and a $\sigma'\in\operatorname{Aut}(Y)$ such that $g=\sigma'\circ f$.

This is easy to show after proving a few useful lemmas from the two given definitions: First, show that the composition of isomorphisms are isomorphisms. Second, show that the inverse of an isomorphism is an isomorphism. These both follow quickly from the axioms above. Then, let $\sigma = g\circ f^{-1}$ and $\sigma'=f^{-1}\circ g$. These are isomorphisms by the two lemmas I suggest, but are also maps $X\rightarrow X$ and $Y\rightarrow Y$ - thus automorphisms - by the properties of composition.

Comment: Thanks this looks interesting, it seems the notion of morphism in a "category" is alot more general and encompasses most of the definitions I've seen so far in abstract algebra. Can I try learning more about this category theory now? Or do you think it would be better to wait till I go through a complete course on abstract algebra? Wouldn't it be better to understand this more general idea of "morphisms", then to look at special cases of them? Or would it be bad because I won't have an appreciation for the generality?

Comment: @jsmith2033 I would recommend against learning category theory until after you have had more "algebra". The abstractness and generality of category theory means the interesting results (other than the very trivial ones like the one mentioned) are quite hard and not very intuitive. It is much easier to work with it once you have a firm grounding in "basic algebra" (group theory, algebras, rings and modules) when a lot of the things done in category theory fall into place better. This is just my opinion though and I don't particularly like category theory.

Comment: @DRF I would say most of the basic results are actually quite easy, e.g. the proof of the Yoneda lemma is completely mechanical. Perhaps that's "trivial", but you can go surprisingly far with a handful of relatively easy to prove categorical results. I do completely agree that it isn't very intuitive without context or applications. It's also the case that most resources for learning category theory do assume a breadth of mathematical knowledge.

Comment: @DerekElkins I think the Yoneda lemma is perfect example of what I meant though perhaps didn't manage to convey correctly. While the proof of the lemma is mechanical (and thus I suppose not hard per se.) even just the statement is very abstract. Having not done category for ages I just went to look at the statement and realized that after 5 minutes reading it I still had no clue what it was trying to say. Wikipedia though gives a link to Cayley's theorem which elucidates the idea withing a couple seconds. This illustrates IMO that knowing "basic algebra" helps immensely to get Cat. theory.

Comment: @jsmith2033 I think that it's good to know that categories exist, and to understand how the algebra you learn fits into them. In particular, category theory concepts like universal properties show up everywhere. For instance, a direct product of groups may defined solely by the category they live in due to their [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Universal_property). The same may be said of abelianization, free products of groups, kernels, images, and all sorts of things. It takes a lot of work to understand, but it's worthwhile.